# Xdebug on Docker doesn't work with PhpStorm

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm, xdebug, docker-compose

I'm quite new in Docker. I can't connect xdebug on Docker container to PhpStorm IDE.

I spend a lot of time for searching how to solve with negative result.
I'm pretty sure I tried everything I found and bit more solution.

I know here is a lot of text but I hope someone will get it :D

My PhpStorm is v 8.0.3

My actual docker-compose snip:

```
ports:
- "8081:8081"
- "80:80"
- "443:443"
expose:
- "9001"
links:
- magedb_m1
environment:
XDEBUG_CONFIG: "remote_host=172.17.0.1"
PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=docker"
XDEBUG_CONFIG: "idekey=PHPSTORM"
PHP_XDEBUG_ENABLED: 1
volumes:
- ./project/:/var/www/html/
```

xdebug.ini:

```
[xdebug]

zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.idkey = "PHPSTORM"

xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
; This is the default Docker gateway
xdebug.remote_host=172.17.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
```

PhpStorm PHP settings:

http://img.ctrlv.in/img/16/10/02/57f0d57039ac8.png

IPs from my local:

```
1: lo: mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp4s0f1: mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
link/ether 14:dd:a9:0b:ee:74 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.2.104/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global dynamic enp4s0f1
valid_lft 315356022sec preferred_lft 315356022sec
inet6 fe80::16dd:a9ff:fe0b:ee74/64 scope link
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: virbr0: mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN
link/ether 52:54:00:d5:ef:9c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: virbr0-nic: mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master virbr0 state DOWN qlen 500
link/ether 52:54:00:d5:ef:9c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: docker0: mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP
link/ether 02:42:b4:ad:cc:ab brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 172.17.0.1/16 scope global docker0
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::42:b4ff:fead:ccab/64 scope link
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: br-c2e824564ce6: mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN
link/ether 02:42:44:61:39:53 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 172.18.0.1/16 scope global br-c2e824564ce6
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
34: veth29f09f2@if33: mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP
link/ether da:96:0c:3e:78:bd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
inet6 fe80::d896:cff:fe3e:78bd/64 scope link
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
36: vethddad676@if35: mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP
link/ether 2e:26:7c:1b:7c:0b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
inet6 fe80::2c26:7cff:fe1b:7c0b/64 scope link
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

IPs from container with xdebug

```
1: lo: mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
35: eth0@if36: mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
link/ether 02:42:ac:11:00:03 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
inet 172.17.0.3/16 scope global eth0
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::42:acff:fe11:3/64 scope link
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

On container xdebug.ini exist in:

```
etc/php/5.6/mods-available/xdebug.ini
```

I tried different remote host address (172.17.0.3 / 172.17.0.2 / 172.17.41.1 / much more). Different xdebug.ini options

Can you give me a tip how to solve it?

Comment: 1) Official manual: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Docker+Support+in+PhpStorm 2) You seem to have followed multiple tutorials at the same time which have created a bit of mess. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphpstorm%5D+xdebug+docker

Comment: My PhpStorm is v 8.0.3. I cant install Docker integration ;c

Comment: You do not need Docker integration for debugging via browser therefore you can skip those steps. But you can have a look at right configs etc. For example -- the IP -- you seems to be trying different/random IPs. Why not detect correct one and just use it (e.g. `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]` for example) . I also believe you do not to expose 9001 port .. as it's xdebug that connect to IDE and not other way around; and with exposing port you might prevent PhpStorm from being able to use it.

Comment: In any case -- I suggest to install 2016.3 EAP build (it has free license for 30 days) and test there as new version may have fixed some xdebug-related issues (that's for the case when you set it all up correctly but that still does not work dues to newer xdebug version or whatever else). Once you make it wok you may stick to your v8 or may consider upgrading (if you have such option, of course)

Comment: Thanks for answer and tips.
Without Docker integration i cant create Docker server as it's shown in next steps.
I tried few random IPs, I tried also Docker container IPs and some local IPs.
$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] on local returns to me "::1" / "127.0.0.1".
$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] on Docker container returns to me "172.17.0.1"
I'm sure I should use mapping port "9001:9001" because phpstorm won't listening this port (it is busy). Expose 9001 is not make it bussy and PhpStorm is able to listening it, however I tried without mapping and expose this port also. It is still not working.

Comment: *"I'm sure I should use mapping port "9001:9001" because phpstorm won't listening this port (it is busy)"* That's the problem -- PhpStorm SHOULD be listening this port (after you activate "phone handle" icon) and it should not be busy otherwise .. as it's the way how xdebug works -- just read the docs: https://xdebug.org/docs/remote

Comment: Ohh sorry. I mean I **Shouldn't** use mapping! Just misspelling.
mapping "9001:9001" make this port busy. However expose 9001 don't make it busy

Comment: Problem generate because of Centos make some awkward firewall settings...